# Im trying to remove empty children from my d3js tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to delete empty children from my d3js tree when i filter some data.

[image: Here its my console.log]

Here is my code i think i have to work on for remove empty children.

```
// Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
        var treeData = treeObject.treemap(treeObject.root);


        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = treeData.descendants().filter(function (d) {
            if (d.data.children > 0) {
                return d.data.value;
            }
        });
        var links = nodes.slice(1);
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're filtering for `d.data.children > 0` but in your object example you have two types of objects

1. an object which contains `name`, `value`, `children`, etc
2. an empty array (which I'm assuming is the child you would like to remove)

Without seeing how you're getting the `children` array in the first place, I would suggest you try fixing your upstream process which results in an empty array being in this collection. Otherwise, here is a way to clean up the data before you start injecting it into your d3 chart:

```js
let data = {
    name: 'Company A',
    value: 0,
    children: [
        { name: 'Exchanges', value: 0, children: [{...}], type: 'node', url: '#' },
        { name: 'Operations', value: 0, children: [{...}], type: 'node', url: '#' },
        { name: 'Management', value: 0, children: [{...}], type: 'node', url: '#' },
        [],
        { name: 'Support', value: 0, children: [{...}], type: 'node', url: '#' }
    ]
}

const filterFunc = (node) => {
    // make sure we are working with the right data here to prevent errors
    if (node && node.children && Array.isArray(node.children)) {

        // filter out any children which are not objects
        // you can put more logic here for even better data hygiene, 
        //    such as checking for required fields like `name`
        node.children = node.children.filter(child => !Array.isArray(child));

    } else {
        // here you can ensure each node has a valid `children` property
        node.children = []
    }

    // recursively call `filterFunc` down the tree until all nodes are validated
    node.children.forEach(child => filterFunc(child));
}

// call `filterFunc` on the root node
filterFunc(data);

// I didn't test this part, but you probably need to `.length` your array check
var nodes = treeData.descendants()
                .filter(function (d) {
                    if (d.data.children.length > 0) {
                        return d.data.value ;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Testing locally, my original filter of `typeof child === 'object'` didn't work because `typeof [] === 'object'`. I have updated the answer to use `!Array.isArray(child)` instead for our filter.

Comment: Thank you! It's work for remove the children. Now i try to redraw my d3js tree with not empty children.